# React generic useFetch state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm trying to write a custom hook useFetch that makes many requests for different data.

The problem is that I can't typing my date correctly, I have state like this.

```
interface IState<T> {
   data:  T | T[]
   loading: boolean,
   error: boolean,
}
```

Initial state

```
const initialState = {
   data: [],
   loading: false,
   error: false,
}
```

useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        setData((prevState) => ({...prevState, loading: true}));
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => response.data.results ? response.data.results as T[] : response.data as T)
            .then((data) => (setData((prevState) => ({...prevState, loading: false, data}))))
            .catch(e => {
                setData((prevState) => ({...prevState, error: true}));
                if (e instanceof Error) console.log(e.message);
            })
}, []);
```

When i get response.data.results i have array of objects and when i have response.data i have only one object. I'm trying to return the right type.

I call my function like this useFetch 
and I have result like this MovieType | MovieType[].
I don't need TypeGuard I need only one correct type.

If you see any problems please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you return response.data object in an array? `[response.data] as T[]` Or do you strictly need response.data.results to be array of objects and response.data to be an object only?

Comment: I need response.data as strictly object

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible for this example to have a singular type when unionized.

The generic function has no idea which one it will output as T[] or a T object because of how you defined IState.

You would just have to check if it's an array or not when you read `.data` from the hook.

The only way to have a singular output type would be to remove the union T[] and simply cast both like Sana Mumtaz said.

```js
interface IState<T> {
   data:  T
   loading: boolean,
   error: boolean,
}

const useFetch = <T>(): IState<T> => {
   // ...
   response => (response.data.results ? response.data.results : response.data) as T
}

useFetch<MovieType[]>();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Axios.get<T>`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/cd8989a987f994c79148bb0cacfca3379ca27414/index.d.ts#L359) is a generic function, so you can take advantage of this.

Try

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, loading: true }));
    axios.get<{ results: T[] } | T>(url)
        .then(({ data }) => "results" in data ? data.results : data)
        .then(data => {
            setData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, loading: false, data }))
        })
        .catch(e => {
            setData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, error: true }));
            if (e instanceof Error) console.log(e.message);
        })
}, []);
```

See playground example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUx0gHgCoB8yA3gFDIXIAm2cA-AFzJ7IA+zA2gLrmUA2AezhVQAcyYAjAQL4Q4IADS8K0KAKiTps+UoC+pUjACuIBGGACQyURDD4CACiNQ+TAM5goYgJRMACmoAtsBuEDjE1LRMLLpEZJTIULbOVgECwaEAdEluMgBuEA4RNFhMIEZ8fMhwbsgmANYgAgDuVjXMyLreANyk+gagkLCIKACyAnnAKPGUIHCBEO6eYr0JSdqhACLYi8geXiCivf2yYHtYkEwYF2HjkxBEALwkyILCYkyeRhAKyKrqTHgfFCnQMcGacGAZxsdgiOQqYDcTDuU24nTYyBRDwcACJcgtnHwcd5eJkwAALCAgBxFSJYTreZCPIg4+F8RE45CgOlwZB0HnZCBuBG1JglOAkihkynU8VMuLKSgeHZMkiZdXKyC-cW-N4iQ6AuDAiC6VYM0kIbAIckOf5QeUkRUUTUoZ7EdWZF2-O2fKDfXVCfXiZBA0Kmp1cmDIW1QNT20DK0wQARRgCisfUjJmCQSCEsuVkmTtMbjmQWbjccBsPQj+goXQMEAAHgAHdRnCK6IA)

Comment: I don't know what i do wrong , but i always get MovieType | MovieType[]

Comment: @ntimpt Why do you think that's wrong? If you have an API that has the potential to return an array or a single object, then `MovieType | MovieType[]` is indeed the correct type.  It's now up to you to use `Array.isArray` to disambiguate the actual returned type